# UIWebView not rendering properly after orientation change

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview, orientation, mobile-website

In my app there are 2 UIWebViews. both take the entire screen so only 1 is visible at a time.
When I see UIWebView A, and I rotate the iPad, the HTML is rendered correctly (with all the media queries and css calculations). But when I switch to UIWebView B, the HTML tag is 512 instead of 768, causing all the css calculations to be messed up.
I checked and the window of UIWebView B does trigger orientationchange event (just wrote to console when it did). It's seems that the view is not rendering when not visible or something. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

A hidden UIWebView will not render properly (for instance if hidden and one tries to capture an image of the view), however once shown, page layout is triggered, and it should render correctly at that point (with the current frame size).

A quick guess is to try changing `UIWebView.scalesPageToFit`, I have that set to true and it WFM in the case you describe.

A complex example is https://github.com/brave/browser-ios which has hidden UIWebViews as tabs (hidden == not in any view hierarchy). In that app, one can change the screen orientation then switch to another tab, causing the newly selected tab to be added to the root view hierarchy so that it is shown, and the web page will layout correctly.

Comment: You mean once a user selects a tab, a new UIWebView is pushed to the hierarchy? What happens to the previous tab? is it removed from the hierarchy? if so how would it preserve the state if the user will go back?

Comment: User creates a tab and a new UIWebView created and added to the view hierarchy (yes to first question). Previous tab's UIWebView is removed from the view hierarchy (yes to your next question). When previous tab selected again, that UIWebView is re-added to the view hierarchy. State is preserved as long as the UIWebView is kept in memory (i.e. stored in a variable) when removed from superview.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Not to cause any unexpected results, I ended up 'fixing' the UWebView size right before appearing (viewWillAppear) - the parent has the right size.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing the UIWebView size in viewWillAppear. took the size from it's superview:

```
UIWebView* webView = (UIWebView*)self.webView;
[webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.superview.frame.size.width, self.view.superview.frame.size.height)];
```